# How to use Nearby Share to send files from an Android phone to a Windows PC?

Tags: wi-fi, file-transfer, windows

I occasionally need to transfer files from my phone to my PC. Connecting a wire is much hassle and Bluetooth transfer is slow. It seems Nearby Share allows sharing over both Bluetooth/Wi-Fi, whichever is available. Both my PC (Asus Windows 10) and Android device (OnePlus Android 12) are connected on the same Wi-Fi network, so I should be able to take advantage of it for fast file transfer.

Both my PC and phone are running Nearby Share. Yet, when I try to send a file from the phone to the PC, it is stuck on the "scanning" step. The phone does not detect my PC as a possible recipient, even when my PC is set to "I can share or receive content from: Everyone nearby". I am not sure what other setting needs to be changed.

**Question:** How to transfer a file from an Android phone to Windows PC using the built-in Nearby Share feature over Wi-Fi when both devices are connected over the same Wi-Fi network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android just launched the exact feature I needed as a new dedicated application for Windows: [The New Nearby Share Beta App for Windows | Android](https://www.android.com/better-together/nearby-share-app/)

It requires a Google login which I'm not a big fan of. But at least this is an answer to the original question in case anyone is looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The Nearby Share in Android (made by Google as a system utility in latest versions of Play Services) and the Nearby Share in Windows are two different software utilities.

An alternate way should be using MixPlorer to set up an FTP server from Android and connecting it to Windows File Explorer (make sure to increase the FTP timeout in MixPlorer since the default is 5 mins afaik)